# Debug inside of AIDL generated file in Eclipse or intellij Idea

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, aidl

I have developed an android application contains an activity and a remote service which are using AIDL. I try to debug inside of the AIDL generated file(contains stub and proxy) in eclipse or intellij idea but when I put breakpoint inside the generated file or in my activity program where a command try to call remote method, it won’t go inside the generated file.

Do you have any idea how debug inside of the generated file?

Br,
Ra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
I had forgot to put ":remote" in service android tag in androidManifest.xml .it should be like below.

```
    <service android:name=".RemoteService" android:process=":remote">
    </service>
```

if you don't put the ":remote" android os take it as local service.